# MYSQL: SELECT DISTINCT only show rows which are unique

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, distinct

I only want to see the rows where the column 'Stadt'(=City) isn´t equal to 'Hauptstadt'(=Capital).
my table looks like:

```
+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
| Name                 | Stadt             | Land                     | Hauptstadt    |
+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
| Kunstmuseum          | Bern              | Schweiz                  | Bern          |
| Musée Picasso        | Paris             | Frankreich               | Paris         |
| Museum Ludwig        | Köln              | Deutschland              | Berlin        |
| Museum of Modern Art | New York          | United States of America | Washington DC |
| Städel               | Frankfurt am Main | Deutschland              | Berlin        |
+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
```

I only want to see(desired output):

```
+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
| Name                 | Stadt             | Land                     | Hauptstadt    |
+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
| Museum Ludwig        | Köln              | Deutschland              | Berlin        |
| Museum of Modern Art | New York          | United States of America | Washington DC |
| Städel               | Frankfurt am Main | Deutschland              | Berlin        |
+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
```

I tried it this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, Stadt, Land ,Hauptstadt 
FROM Museum 
GROUP BY 'Name', 'Stadt', 'Land', 'Hauptstadt' 
ORDER BY Name;
```

Output:

```
+----------------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------+
| Name                 | Stadt    | Land                     | Hauptstadt    |
+----------------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------+
| Museum of Modern Art | New York | United States of America | Washington DC |
+----------------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------+
```

How should my SELECT look like to get my desired ouput?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you need `DISTINCT`? Your requirement sounds like `Stadt <> Hauptstadt`...

Comment: Just so you know for the future; DISTINCT is a function so if you employ it the syntax should be DISTINCT(some_col). And based on your criteria, you should accept Gordon's answer below.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **not** a function, and according to the [specification](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) there are no parentheses: `SELECT [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]...`. You could use parentheses, but `DISTINCT` would still affect all selected columns, so that would be confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes in the `group by` are messing you up.  First, only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Second, you almost never need `group by` with `select distinct`.  Third, you need a `where` clause for your condition.  So try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, Stadt, Land ,Hauptstadt 
FROM Museum 
WHERE Stadt <> Hauptstadt
ORDER BY Name;
```

Comment: I suspect the DISTINCT here is not really required - the OP was confused about what DISTINCT does, and there is no evidence in the example data and required results that DISTINCTION is required.

Comment: @Gordon This works great! Thanks for showing that it works with DISTINCT aswell.

Comment: As @mc100 points out, your query is probably fine without the `distinct`.  `select distinct` slows down queries because the engine has to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

we need to group it by name and just compare the two columns if is equal or not

```
SELECT * FROM Museum WHERE Stadt != Hauptstadt GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know it coukd be easy like that.